# Why can't I get this array to properly pull string from a file, it does fine the first pass, but when it loops it fails?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, getline

I am trying to pull a series of video game console names from a text file. The text file reads as such,

```
Nintendo Entertainment System
57
Sega Genesis
34
Microsoft Xbox 360
58
Sony PlayStation 4
261
Atari 2600
26
Nintendo Game Cube
52
```

So what I set up was a do while to get save the names in an array, then their prices, then repeat. The problem seems to be it gets the first console name, gets the first price, then when it repeats it fails and no more names load and the prices go to -858993460.

This is my loadArrays function -

```
void loadArrays(string consoleNames[], int consolePrices[], int& size)

{
    ifstream dataFile("prices.txt");

    int i = 0;
    int cont = 1;

    do
    {
        getline(dataFile, consoleNames[i]);
        dataFile >> consolePrices[i];
    
        i++;
        size += 1;
        /*if (consolePrices = 0)
        {
            size = size - 1;
            for (int j = 0; i < size; j++)
            {
                consoleNames[j] = consoleNames[j + 1];
                consolePrices[j] = consolePrices[j + 1];
            }
            cont = 0;
        }*/
        if (size == 6)
            break;
    } while (cont == 1);
}
```

And this is what I get back
[Failed Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP4rc.png)

The problem could be the getline not moving to the next string properly?

Comment: The `dataFile >> consolePrices[i];` statement does *not* read the ending newline. Guess what the next call to `std::getline` will read. A few seconds stepping through the code in a debugger would have given you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataFile >> consolePrices[i];` on the first iteration leaves `\n` in the istream.

Then `getline(dataFile, consoleNames[i]);` extracts that new line symbol on the second iteration and you get the empty string. After that `dataFile >> consolePrices[i];` tries to read int but meets the string `Sega Genesis`, leaves the `consolePrices[i];` uninitialized and the istream in fail. Further iterations can't read the failed istream.